# Problem with bin sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bin

```
  //element of chain.     
    struct studentRecord 
            {
           int score;
           string* name;

           int operator !=(studentRecord x) const
              {return (score != x.score);}
        };


    // binsort,  theChain is a single linked list of students and its element is student Record

         void binSort(chain<studentRecord>& theChain, int range)
            {// Sort by score.

               // initialize the bins
               chain<studentRecord> *bin;
               bin = new chain<studentRecord> [range + 1];

               // distribute student records from theChain to bins
               int numberOfElements = theChain.size();
               for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++)
               {
                  studentRecord x = theChain.get(0);
                  theChain.erase(0);
                  bin[x.score].insert(0,x);
               }

               // collect elements from bins
               for (int j = range; j >= 0; j--)
                  while (!bin[j].empty())
                  {
                     studentRecord x = bin[j].get(0);
                     bin[j].erase(0);  ////////// here
                     theChain.insert(0,x);
                  }

               delete [] bin;
            }
```

`chain<studentRecord>` is a **single linked list**; In the bin sort,  bin is a pointer to a `bin[arrange +1]` whose elements are `chain<studentRecord>` . The code `bin[j].erase(i)` will `delete` the node `i`. `bin[j].get(i)` will get the element (i.e. studentRecord) of node `i`. In the code, `while (!bin[j].empty())` is used to empty the chain, but bin[j] cannot be empty because it is an element array, is that right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bin indeed can be empty.  There's a subtle but important difference between the bin being *empty* and the bin *existing*.  You are correct that the bin is a member of the array, and so there *exists* a bin in position `i` for any `i` that's in bounds in the array.  However, that bin doesn't necessarily have to have anything in it; it could have nothing in it at all if none of the elements in the input list happen to fall into that bin.

There's a good physical analogy to this problem if you have a row of glasses set out on a table and start filling some of them with water.  All the glasses in a row exist and are well-defined, but they don't all have to be empty, especially if you start pouring them out (as you're doing in this bin sort example above).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I thought bin[j] would store the chainNode but actually, it stores the `firstNodePointer`, which will pointer to the memory of the `firstNode` that is located in heap. So even if I use `delete firstNode`, the `firstNodePointer` still exists in the `bin[j]` but the space of `firstNode` is empty.